# How to play the recorded audio using audioplayer package in flutter

Tags: flutter, chat, record, audio-player

I am trying to add voice message feature on my chat app. I am using `record_mp3` package to record voice and `audioplayer` to play it. but `audioplayer` is not accepting the url. i used this package to play network and asset audio but couldn't found any help to help recorded file.

here is the method i used to record audio

```
startRecord() async {
    
      recordFilePath = await getFilePath();
      RecordMp3.instance.start(recordFilePath, (type) {
        setState(() {});
      });
    
    setState(() {});

    log("recordFilePath  $recordFilePath");
    
  }
```

this is method i am using to play audio

```
Future<void> play(String url) async {
    await _audioPlayer.play(url,);
  }
```

i am getting this error in play function of audioplayer

```
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Source'.
```

kindly help how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In play function, you are passing string url directly, but play function expect Source, please check the below example.

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
audioPlayer.play(UrlSource('https://example.com/my-audio.wav'));
```